# No overload for 'getNext' matches delegate 'EventHandler'

Tags: c#, winforms

here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
  nextButton.Click += getNext;
}

private void getNext(object sender , System.EventHandler e)
{
   this.Close();
}
}
```

Visual Studio (2019) saying that "No overload for 'getNext' matches delegate 'EventHandler'" despite getNext haveing System.EventHandler as one of the overloads, i dont really understand whats going on here

Comment: The signature of getNext() should be `(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [proper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click?view=netcore-3.1) method signature:

```
private void getNext(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```